# Class for reusable layout android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I have a reusable layout called title

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/lesson_title"
    android:textSize="@dimen/title" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/title_book"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:text="@string/book" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/title_buy"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:text="@string/buy"
    android:visibility="gone" />
```

I include this in most of my activities and that works fine.

To handle the clicks and the title text I have to do this in every activity

```
TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title_text);
title.setText(R.string.some_title);
Button book = (Button) findViewById(R.id.title_book);
Button buy = (Button) findViewById(R.id.title_buy);
```

and for clicks

```
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {

    case R.id.title_book:
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "book", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;

    case R.id.title_buy:
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "buy", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
    }
}
```

Is there a way I can create a class to handle this? It could have an init method which I could call from the activities to set up the text on the title only because the buttons will do the same function everytime.

This is what I have tried to do based on the answer by Udi

```
public class CustomTitle extends RelativeLayout{

private Context mContext;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
private ViewHolder myViewHolder;
String mText = "hello";

public CustomTitle(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.mContext = context;
    //this.mText = text;

    inflate();
    bindViews();
}

private void inflate() {

    if(layoutInflater == null){
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    layoutInflater.inflate(com.callan.app.R.layout.title, this, true);      
}

private void bindViews() {
    // bind all views here

    if(myViewHolder == null){
        myViewHolder = new ViewHolder();
    }

    myViewHolder.title_text = (TextView) findViewById(com.callan.app.R.id.title_text);
    myViewHolder.book = (Button) findViewById(com.callan.app.R.id.title_book);
    myViewHolder.buy = (Button) findViewById(com.callan.app.R.id.title_buy);

    if(Callan.getMyCredit() > 0){

        myViewHolder.buy.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        myViewHolder.book.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }else{

        myViewHolder.buy.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        myViewHolder.book.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    myViewHolder.title_text.setText(mText);     
}

class ViewHolder{

    TextView title_text;
    Button book;
    Button buy;
}

public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {

    case com.callan.app.R.id.title_book:
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "book", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;

    case com.callan.app.R.id.title_buy:
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "buy", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
    }
}
```

}

and in my xml I have

```
<com.callan.custom_views.CustomTitle xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:orientation="vertical" >

//my views
```

Then in my activity I have after onCreate

```
CustomTitle cTitle = new CustomTitle(this);
```

Exception

```
04-30 14:24:44.440: E/AndroidRuntime(7184): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.callm.app/com.callan.app.Lessons}:       android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class        com.callm.custom_views.CustomTitle
 04-30 14:24:44.440: E/AndroidRuntime(7184): Caused by: android.view.InflateException:       Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class com.callm.custom_views.CustomTitle
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create custom class which extends FrameLayout/or anything else you want.
in it's constructor create 2 methods: inflate() and  bindViews()

```
public class CustomView extends FrameLayout {

private Context mContext;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
// All views here

public CustomView (Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.mContext = context;
    inflate();
    bindViews();

}

private void inflate() {
    layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.your_xml_layout, this, true);
}

private void bindViews() {
    // bind all views here
}
}
```

add your methods and you'll be able to use this class wherever you need.

Comment: I've tried to do it and so far I'm getting an Inflate Exception

04-30 14:24:44.440: E/AndroidRuntime(7184): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.callm.app/com.callan.app.Lessons}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class com.callm.custom_views.CustomTitle
04-30 14:24:44.440: E/AndroidRuntime(7184): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class com.callm.custom_views.CustomTitle

Comment: Alright I get it now, I no longer need the include I just use this new view in my activity's layout where I would include.

Comment: you don't need view holder also, just hold references to your view as members in this class. nested class is unnecessary

Comment: can I handle the clik event in the class as well. It works fine now but click seem to crash the app.

Comment: yes you can. debug it and check where the exception is thrown. probably nullpointerexception

Answer (score 1):

You can create custom widget via extending some standard view

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html#basic