# android display records randomly on views

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm creating a quiz app in android. I want to make my app as efficient as it can be. I'm a newbie so pardon my structure in game development. What I've tried so far is the hard-coded way, I have 10 questions from my database. This is the structure of my table:

_id, type, question, answer1, answer2, answer3, correctanswer

What I have done so far is I created 10 layouts for each question. But they are not random. What I wanna achieve is, the questions must be random and I just wanna use a single layout to display the questions and answers. How do I do that? Sample codes or tutorials might help me. I would gladly appreciate your help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to use as much as you can in custom views, instead of creating same layout over and over again. [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16299225/class-for-reusable-layout-android/16299538#16299538)
2. Get you data from database into ArrayList and implement random method which gets item from list and then delete it (or put it somewhere else).

I would suggest you to rewrite your db structure again as one table with 5-6 columns is very thin for major changes in the future.
You need to know first what you want to do and how, then you need to ask how :)

good luck

Comment: Hello thanks. I know what I wanna do, but I don't know how to do it. As I described in my question above.

Comment: we can't help you write your application from 0, try it yourself, investigate, and then ask specific question, start with building your database and insert X rows, retrieve them into views (list or something else), start the flow yourself, and then if you have issues..and probably you'll have...ask them :)